# Uncompression error -- System halted on Xubuntu VM when running with Linux 5.4.0-48-generic but not 5.4.0-47-generic

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox

VirtualBox Xubuntu machine running ubuntu version 18.04.5 LTS, when attempting to boot with Linux 5.4.0-48-generic results in a unresponsive machine with error message "Uncompression error -- System halted" being displayed.

I have been running this machine for months without issue. Host os is Windows 10 recently updated (around the same time, but no idea if it is related) to version 2004. I believe I was encountering some minor issue with updating the guest before this more major issue started.

Guest boots without issue if I force it to run with Linux 5.4.0-47-generic.

Comment: Are you sure it's not the new initramfs image that was improperly written? Didn't the /boot filesystem get full? etc. Can you remove and reinstall the new kernel, but check for errors displayed during installation

Comment: @A.B issue seems to have been resolved after reinstalling the new kernel, no errors came up during the installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue seems to be resolved after reinstalling the kernel and updating initramfs per the answers to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/253244/reinstall-latest-kernel) question.